# How to add a line break with table-cell formatting

Tags: html, css

I have a form setup using custom css. I need to put a space in between the input fields and align the check boxes.
here is a plunkr of what I have
[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RNVTICxVfyYGICYklRuI?p=preview)

```
<style> form {display: table;} p {display: table-row;}label {display: table-cell; }input {display: table-cell; } </style>
```

The labels for the checkboxes on the left column need to be aligned right with there checkboxes on the left of them. 
The check boxes in the right column need to be aligned left with there labels to the right of them.

Comment: Include the *relevant* CSS *and* HTML code in the question itself, explain clearly what you want (a space between something isn’t clear enough), and describe how your best effort at it has failed.

Comment: Sorry... It is a bit confusing. Which one needs to be on the left? The label or the checkboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some top and bottom margin to your `label` and `input` elements:

```
label, input{
    margin:5px 0px;
}
```

Then you can fix your checkbox issue by nesting the `input` inside the `label` tag like so:

```
<p>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="currentItem.CertPayroll" /> 
        Certified Payroll
    </label>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the "display: table-cell" style on the labels for the checkboxes (but not the others) will kick them over.  Better ways to structure the overall layout, but that's a quick and dirty solution.